# Use Windows 10 or Linux as mouse to control other PC via USB

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

One of my windows tablets needs to reinstall windows, but the touch on the tablet isn't recognized while trying to install. Is it possible to use another Windows 10 or Linux machine to act as a keyboard or mouse over USB? similar to using a raspberry pi as a HID mouse or something.

Comment: Using computer as a mouse is probably not the most optimal solution here. Can you use a bluetooth mouse or a keyboard?

Comment: To act as an USB device, the Windows/Linux machine needs an USB client or USB OTG port, which normal PCs don't have. This question has been asked before, and there are answers with more details.

Comment: If not, I'll just wait for a OTG Cable to come in the mail.

Comment: @dirkt, can you put that as an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Comment: It's really a duplicate, so it should be marked as a duplicate, but I don't have the time right now to search for the existing question(s). Note that an OTG **cable** won't turn the USB ports on the motherboard into OTG, so this probably won't work. If you find any hardware that provides an USB OTG port to a PC, I'd be very interested to know the exact brand etc.